# Highlight selected tab in menu

Tags: css, asp.net, navigation

I have the following tabbed navigation setup in my master page:

```
<div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="../default.aspx">Logo</a>
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                <div class="buttons">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="../default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../books/books.aspx">Books</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../contacts/aboutus.aspx">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../contacts/contact.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

For example when I click Home tab, I'd like it to remain highlighted (ex. `background-color: #1087a4;`). What is the recommended way to accomplish this? And does this have to be implemented in the Master Page?

Comment: I had ran through the same problem , what you can do is ,Create a selected class style(.selected{background-color:lightgrey}) On the page load of all the links(such as books.aspx,aboutus.aspx) you can set the selected class to the ID of href($('#ID').addClass('.selected').make sure you have removed the selected class from all the other links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give`ID`, `runat="server"` to each link. And find that link from the `Content Page` and give the style over there.

**For Example:**

### `Master Page`

```
<div id="header">
   <div id="logo">
      <a href="../default.aspx">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
      <div class="buttons">
         <ul>
           <li><a id="lbtnHome" runat="server" href="../default.aspx">Home</a></li>
           <li><a id="lbtnBooks" runat="server" href="../books/books.aspx">Books</a></li>
           <li><a id="lbtnAbout" runat="server" href="../contacts/aboutus.aspx">About Us</a></li>
           <li><a id="lbtnContact" runat="server" href="../contacts/contact.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

### `Home Page`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var link = document.getElementById('<%=Master.FindControl("lbtnHome").ClientID %>');
   link.style.color = '#1087a4';
</script>
```

### `Books Page`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var link = document.getElementById('<%=Master.FindControl("lbtnBooks").ClientID %>');
   link.style.color = '#1087a4';
</script>
```

Like the same for all other pages.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to the home list item and give that a background-color of #1087a4.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="../default.aspx">Logo</a>
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                <div class="buttons">
                <ul>
                    <li class="selected"><a href="../default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../books/books.aspx">Books</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../contacts/aboutus.aspx">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../contacts/contact.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.selected {
    background-color:#1087a4;
}
```

[<kbd>**JSFiddle demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/rb3f34nh/)

Comment: This highlights only the Home tab. I want to change the back color for each tab when I nagivate through menu.

Comment: I see that your navigation links to pages, you can assign the class `selected` on each page to the right list item. So for `default.aspx` you'd have it on the first one, for `books.aspx` you'd have it on the second one, etc. You can also use jQuery but it's useless as you will link to another page anyways. See demo for code: http://jsfiddle.net/rb3f34nh/1/

Comment: And if you don't want to link to pages at all but just highlight the word you click on you could use this code: http://jsfiddle.net/rb3f34nh/3/

Answer (score 0):

can u Please check the below link I hope It would be helpful to you

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jai17/ckcmvnda/2/)

CSS:

```
.selected a{ color: red}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".menu li").click(function(){
    var str = $(this).index();
    $(".menu li").removeClass("selected");
   $(this).addClass( "selected" );
});
```

Comment: this doesn't deselect